# How process multiple files at once?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have to use this [vera++](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/) tool against multiple `*.cpp` and `*.h` files.
I accepts a filename as a parameter.
How to search for `*.cpp` files and send them to `vera++`?
Is this an one-liner or will I need a batch script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current folder only:

```
for %i in (*.cpp *.h) do vera++ "%~i"
```

Including subfolders:

```
for /r . %i in (*.cpp *.h) do vera++ "%~i"
```

`/r .` means "start in the current folder". If you want to specify a different folder name, use `for /r newfolder`.

Comment: How do I do that on Windows XP? It's not working.

Comment: @Jader: How *exactly* is it not working? (Also, don't accept answers without testing them first.)

Comment: It works in the command line, but when inside a `bat` file it results  `~i" was unexpected at this time` (rough translation from portuguese)

Comment: @Jader: When using `for` inside a batch file, you need to double the `%`s – like this: `for %%i in (*.cpp *.h) do vera++ "%%~i"`

Answer (score 3):

It's a one-liner in the documentation, certainly.  Here are the options:

- **Do what the documentation says.**  The documentation says

  ```
  find . -name '*.h' | xargs vera++ -profile my_favourite
  ```

  And with an appropriate toolset, such as Microsoft's own [downloadable SFUA utility toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F) that runs on the Windows 7 [Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772343.aspx) (which comes in the box with Windows 7 Ultimate edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 — For Windows XP, one can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778) and install [Services for UNIX version 3.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb496506.aspx).) one has tools such as `find` and `xargs` for Windows.  There are, of course, also [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net./), [cygwin](http://cygwin.com./), and [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net./).
- **If you are using [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccledes.htm) you can use the built-in [`SELECT` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/select.htm)** to interactively select the files to process:

  ```
  SELECT vera++ [*]
  ```

  Note the square brackets, which cause all of the filenames to be combined into one command.
- **Using an orthodox file manager**, such as [File Commander for Windows](http://silk.apana.org.au./fc.html) or [FAR](http://farmanager.com./), you can similarly select the files to process interactively, and paste them onto the command line with the appropriate keypress.
- **If you are using [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccledes.htm) you can use the built-in [`FOR` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/for.htm)** to process files after finding them (say) with the [`DIR` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/dir.htm):

  ```
  DIR /B /S *.cpp;*.h|FOR F IN (@CON) do vera++ %F
  ```

  or just process them directly since `FOR` has a recursion option:

  ```
  FOR /R F IN (*.cpp;*.h) DO vera++ %F
  ```

  This of course runs the command once per individual file found.
- Or you can do what Grawity said.

Comment: it happens that windows xp already has a `find.exe` (for searching strings inside files) then you have to specify which find do you want to use